# Paths missing inside Virtualenv to own venv libraries

Tags: python, path, virtualenv

After porting to a new server, my flask app does not work anymore. The problem is that in the virtualenv that I use there are no pointers to the /venv/ libraries. When I check:

```
>>>> import sys; sys.path
['', '/usr/local/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7', 
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', 
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', 
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

No pointers to my /venv path and therefore no pointers to the libraries that my app depends on. What is the right way to solve this?

Comment: Did you activate the virtualenv?